# Google Sheets: Query and list the last 5 values in a column if the column contains a number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use Sparkline for a spreadsheet to show a trend of the last 5 soccer matches, where A and B are the goals, and C are the resulting points.

In column C, the points are only generated if values are entered for the goals and goals conceded, i.e. the columns are not empty.

| A (Goals) | B (Conceded) | C (Points) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 |  |  |
| 4 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 |

As you see, in row 3, column c is empty.

What I basically try to achieve, is to create a list where the last 5 entries which are not empty / null, are listed:

| C (Points) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

Is used this formula, but it somehow does not work

`=query(J15:J114,"select * offset "&count(J15:J114)-5)`

shorturl.at/gHPY9 (example result picture)

Tried to find a solution myself, but am stuck.

Best,
Feal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query()` with a `where` clause, like this:

```
=query( 
  J15:J114, 
  "where J is not null 
   offset " & max(0, count(J15:J114) - 5), 
  0 
)
```